# How to change tooltip colour?

Tags: java, button

[image: yellow window]

How can i create button, when you go across with mouse show that yellow window.

```
Open.setToolTipText (Open); // how change it from blue to yellow?
```

Comment: It's called a tooltip that is used when the user hovers over a JButton. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html

Comment: `Open.setToolTipText (Open);`
i make that code, but it show only blue window
how can i change colour to yellow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message displayed when the user hovers over a JButton is called a tooltip.

You can create one using the code found in the Java tutorial here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html

To customize the background of the tooltip, you can do one of two things:

- Change the [Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)
- Use the following code to change the tooltip alone:

  ```
  UIManager.put("ToolTip.background", new ColorUIResource(255, 247, 200)); //#fff7c8
  Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(76,79,83));    //#4c4f53
  UIManager.put("ToolTip.border", border);
  ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(15000); // 15 second delay  
  setToolTipText(message); // Message to display
  ```

Source: [Moon Ocean Oracle Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/moonocean/entry/change_properties_of_java_tooltip)

Comment: You do not have to use the `Border` or `.setDismissDelay` if you would not like to; I included it in case you would like to further customize the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

The style of the tooltip can be changed in two ways:

1. It can be changed in the css as follows:

   .tooltip{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#e2ecfe, #99bcfd);
   }
2. It can be changed in the code itself as follows:

   final Tooltip t = new Tooltip(advancePlayBaclFlagVo.getDescriptions() + "["+advancePlayBaclFlagVo.getPlantedDateTime()+"]");
       t.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");